# Recording video in Appium Android

Tags: java, android, appium, selenide

I have the following implementation of recording screen for appium android tests.

```
androidDriver.startRecordingScreen(new AndroidStartScreenRecordingOptions() {
        @Override
        public AndroidStartScreenRecordingOptions withTimeLimit(Duration timeLimit) {
            return super.withTimeLimit(Duration.ofMinutes(7)).withVideoSize("720x1280").withBitRate(2000000);
        }
    });
```

But it does not record more than 3 mins which is the default time. I have increased it to 7 mins no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Appium uses [ffmpeg](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg) to merge the videos . Make sure that your machine should have this . Otherwise it will not able to merge the videos and you will get only the last 3 minutes of recording.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below comment on `java-client` repository from appium as,

https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidStartScreenRecordingOptions.java#L102

```
/**
 * The maximum recording time. The default and maximum value is 180 seconds (3 minutes).
 * Setting values greater than this or less than zero will cause an exception. The minimum
 * time resolution unit is one second.
 *
 * <p>Since Appium 1.8.2 the time limit can be up to 1800 seconds (30 minutes).
 * Appium will automatically try to merge the 3-minutes chunks recorded
 * by the screenrecord utility, however, this requires FFMPEG utility
 * to be installed and available in PATH on the server machine. If the utility is not
 * present then the most recent screen recording chunk is going to be returned as the result.</p>
 *
 * @param timeLimit The actual time limit of the recorded video.
 * @return self instance for chaining.
 */
```